# Georeferencing a jpeg in QGIS but the scale is way off

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing, scale

I've gone through the really helpful walk-through(s) of how to georeference a jpeg in order to make it a layer, but after inputting the coordinates (either by typing in actual coordinates or clicking "From map canvas" and aligning points) and loading the new layer, the scale is way off (and I think the jpeg isn't even remotely in the right place--hard to tell because of how off the scale is).

Any ideas?

Comment: With most jpegs i georef it is other peoples images onto background mapping. The should be no such thing as scale for the georef. the points should be where the points are.

Answer (score 6):

You have to decide whether you want to enter coordinates in lat/lon, or from a background map with a projected CRS (e.g. in metres). For the first choice, you have to set the target CRS to WGS84 (EPSG:4326), and don't mix up lat and long values.

For the second choice, the target CRS **must** be set to the same CRS as the **project** CRS. This can be different from the background map original CRS.

If you load the georeferenced picture to QGIS canvas, check if the CRS is set correctly with `Rightclick -> Set CRS for layer`. Sometimes QGIS sets the CRS for new layers automatically to a CRS that you do not want in your case.

Comment: Hi Andre, I have checked these--both the jpeg and the project are set to the same: NAD83(NSRS2007)--New Jersey in US feet.

EDIT: Whoops...looks like my basemap was NOT in that CRS.  Egg on my face.  Thanks for your help!